# Searching a Google Form response (Google Sheets) for row and column numbers

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am trying to figure out how to search a google forms response (google sheets) in order to find a value of the row and column number to extract data.

I have everything else, but searching for the column and row and I'm not sure how to make a 2D search for this.

Here is the data I want to search and extract, but I don't want all of the data, just specific cells/ranges.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ehA0fXBM6CPBAKfHvBbouRPjOMDxrXSdFI0zMye3G7c/edit?usp=sharing

My plan is to pull the "Employee Name" into another spreadsheet for an overview of who has completed it and at what location on a daily basis. Because the form is always receiving responses I want the script to pull data multiple times a day to show compliance of the form. I want the response to look something like this:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1QyK5c-vxkt5BnM-wM-m80RZCO_29KWoF_isIZBOllvQ/edit?usp=sharing

Here is what I was hoping to get my Google Script to do:
1. Script searches source sheet finds location.
2. Script returns row and column for where the location was listed.
3. Script takes row and column and subtracts 1 from the row and getValue(); of that cell. (Which in this case will be the employee who completed the form.)
4. Script returns the "employee name" to destination sheet based on employee location. (So it is in the right line.)
Result, script pulls data from the form responses and lists who completed it.

I have everything working to pull data from a specific cell/range and paste it to the destination sheet based on location and the date.

Now that I've explained what I'm trying to do, I can explain where I'm stumped. I can't figure out how the repeating for or when command works. I want to search for one specific location and than return the row and column number. Here is the code I have been trying to manipulate, but I can't get it to search in 2d or even the row to return a value int eh for/when command.

```js
function updateVerification() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("1ehA0fXBM6CPBAKfHvBbouRPjOMDxrXSdFI0zMye3G7c");
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  var ss_dest = SpreadsheetApp.openById("1QyK5c-vxkt5BnM-wM-m80RZCO_29KWoF_isIZBOllvQ");
  var sheet_dest = ss_dest.getSheetByName("Destination");
  var rows=ss.getDataRange().getValues();
  var paste = 0;
  for(var r=0; r<rows.length; r++){
    for(var c=0; c<rows[r].length; c++){
      if(rows[r][c] == "Location #1"){
        paste = sheet.getRange(rows[r]+":"+rows[c]).getValue();
        sheet_dest.getRange(2,4).setValue(paste);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

If anyone is able to help me I would greatly appreciate it.

Thanks for any and all help. :)

Comment: You need to call `getDataRange()` with parentheses and `getValues()`, plural.  Its also not clear where `targetRange` is coming from.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm guessing you want something like this:

```
function updateVerification() {
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.openById("1ehA0fXBM6CPBAKfHvBbouRPjOMDxrXSdFI0zMye3G7c");
  var sh=ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  var ss_dest=SpreadsheetApp.openById("1QyK5c-vxkt5BnM-wM-m80RZCO_29KWoF_isIZBOllvQ")
  var sh_dest=ss_dest.getSheetByName("Destination");
  var rows=ss.getDataRange().getValues();
  for(var r=0;r<rows.length;r++) {
    for(var c=0;c<rows[r].length;c++) {
      if(rows[r][c]=="Location #1") {
        sh_dest.appendRow(rows[r]);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

If I remove the cell contents and replace it with the array indices your data would look something like this:

```
[
["row[0][0]","rows[0][1],"rows[0][2]"],
["row[1][0]","rows[1][1],"rows[1][2]"],
["row[2][0]","rows[2][1],"rows[2][2]"],
["row[3][0]","rows[3][1],"rows[3][2]"]//rows[rows.length-1]
]
```

Comment: Would you be so kind to explain how the for section works? I'd really like to understand how "r<rows.length", "appendRow(row[r])" and "rows[r][c]" work so that I can apply them to my code more effectively. I think I understand how they work, but it would be great to get some clarification. Please and Thank you. :)

Comment: @JoshuaGottschalk does that help?

Comment: Ohhh.... Yes that does help. I understand, it's an array. How can I use the r,c to getRange that == "Location #1"? (If I wanted to get that range that was equal to that and move it? Or maybe -1 from the r/c and get something in the same line?)

Comment: I change my code above so reflect what I have currently.

Comment: r is the first index and c is the second.  So the outside loop iterates  over rows with r  and the c iterates over columns.

Comment: If you data started at 'A1' the rows[3][2] would be at 'C4'. Arrays start indexing from zero. But columns and row index from 1.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/192244/discussion-between-cooper-and-neros).